# Read dynamic json property values using JObject c#

Tags: c#, wpf, json, json.net

Part of my Json structre is dynacmic array and i want to read it using Json.Net .
The json structre is

```
{
"objects": [{
    "id": "521daea47288c7794c88c923",
    "name": "Rass",
    "email": "ras@hjsh.com",
    "username": "ras",
    "books": [],
    "devices": [],
    "preferences": [
    {
    "name": "key1",
    "value": [
      {
        "id": "val1Id",
        "params": [
          {
            "name": "set1key",
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "set1key2",
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "set1key3",
            "value": 0.5
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "val2Id",
        "params": [
          {
            "name": "set2key",
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "set2key2",
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "set2key3",
            "value": 0.5
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "language",
    "value": "en_US"
  },
  {
    "name": "page_zoom",
    "value": 1
  }
],
"created": "2013-08-28T08:02:44.000Z"
}],
"meta": {
    "total_count": 1,
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 1000
}
```

}

How can i access the set of preferences in my c# code .
I gets the preference tag from json using the below code

```
   var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        JObject obj = (JObject)jObject["objects"][0]["preferences"][0];
        string pref = "";
        foreach (var pref_item in obj)
        {
            string key = pref_item.Key;               
           //Here i want to check the Value is of type array, then get each item from Array.
            //If its not an array simply read the value
        }
```

Now i want to navigate to each preference items , store the name and value properties. If Value is array i want to access each items in that array .
How can i do it?

Comment: I'd expect it to be pretty simple - it looks like you've already got the code to get the first preference (without the `[0]` at the end it would be all the preferences). So what's going wrong with the code you've got?

Comment: The actual json is slightly different(updated question ) , so i used the code and if i try to Parse without[0]  it returns error "Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'." And if i change the JObject to JArray it returns again exception is not a valid JArray to parse

Comment: Well the preferences itself *is* a `JArray`, but you can ask for any element *within* that `JArray`. So what exactly are you trying to do with the preferences, what code have you tried, and what went wrong? It's hard to help you without concrete requirements.

Comment: Please see the code sample i used in question (Now updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you need based on the somewhat vague requirements, but here's some code which will get you a `Dictionary<string, JToken>` of the preferences:

```
JArray preferences = (JArray)jObject["objects"][0]["preferences"];
var dictionary = preferences.ToDictionary(x => (string) x["name"],
                                          x => x["value"]);

// For example...
Console.WriteLine(dictionary["language"]); // prints en_US
```

You can then do whatever you want with the tokens. Anything where the value itself is an array will have have a `JArray` value. You can test that easily enough:

```
JToken value = dictionary[key];
JArray array = value as JArray;
if (array != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
JToken value = dictionary[key];
if (value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    JArray array = (JArray) value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: @JMat: Well the code I've given already *builds* a dictionary of names and values. What do you need to do that that doesn't achieve?

Comment: Yes it helped to get the values from JSON object. I did few more modifications in code so i can loop through all child and sub childs. (answer edited )

Comment: @JMat: Please don't edit other people's answers to add large chunks of code. That should be an edit on your question, if anything (or a new answer) - although it's not clear that it's useful for other readers, to be honest.

Comment: will follow to do the way in my future posts. thanks for helping to fix the current issue